# Encrypting page contents without SSL

Tags: php, encryption

Is there any way to encrypt the page content so that robots and search engines can't access the content of the website at all. If yes what is the best method?

Comment: With a system that requires logging in, not "encryption".

Answer (score 0):

Use your .htaccess to block all traffic.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from your.ip.address.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a `robots.txt` file to disable search engine indexing, and populate it like so:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```